# Bootstrap progress bar label misaligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using 4 bootsrap progess bar and progess label. But each progress bar is misaligned. The progess bar is not matching with the above progress bar. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below is the code i used. I want to align the above progress bar to the same place as the other. anybody got any solution to solve this issue

```
<style>
.progress {height: 25px;}
.progress .sr-only { position: relative; }
.progress-bar { line-height: 25px; }
.progress-label {float: left;margin-right: em;}
</style>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="margin-top: 76px">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="progress">
            <label class="progress-label"style="font-size: large;"> Total memory:</label>
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <label class="progress-label"style="font-size: large;"> Used memory:</label>
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <label class="progress-label"style="font-size: large;"> Free memory:</label>
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <label class="progress-label"style="font-size: large;"> Memory Usage:</label>
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
      50% Complete (info)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
      60% Complete (warning)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70% Complete (danger)
    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: To sort your problem set the width to the label. Also, you got missing units in your css on line `margin-right: em;`;

Comment: @Jeeva what do you mean by *progess bar is not matching*. Are you talking about the width of the progress bars or alignment or label text

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. use the default bootstrap grid system. Add `.col-xs-3` and `.col-xs-9` classes to the `.progress-label` and `.progress-bar` classes respectively.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .progress {
    height: 25px;
  }
  
  .progress .sr-only {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .progress-bar {
    line-height: 25px;
  }
  
  .progress-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: em;
  }
</style>

<div class="cntainer-fluid">
  <div class="progress">
    <label class="progress-label col-xs-3" style="font-size: large;"> Total memory:</label>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active col-xs-9" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
      40% Complete (success)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <label class="progress-label col-xs-3" style="font-size: large;"> Used memory:</label>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active col-xs-9" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
      50% Complete (success)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <label class="progress-label col-xs-3" style="font-size: large;"> Free memory:</label>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active col-xs-9" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
      60% Complete (success)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <label class="progress-label col-xs-3" style="font-size: large;"> Memory Usage:</label>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active col-xs-9" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70% Complete (success)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
      50% Complete (info)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
      60% Complete (warning)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70% Complete (danger)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Give the `.progress-label` a minimum width

   .progress-label {
     min-width: 150px;
   }

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  .progress {
    height: 25px;
  }
  
  .progress-label {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  
  .progress .sr-only {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .progress-bar {
    line-height: 25px;
  }
  
  .progress-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: em;
  }
</style>


<div class="progress">
  <label class="progress-label" style="font-size: large;"> Total memory:</label>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
    40% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <label class="progress-label" style="font-size: large;"> Used memory:</label>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
    50% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <label class="progress-label" style="font-size: large;"> Free memory:</label>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
    60% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <label class="progress-label" style="font-size: large;"> Memory Usage:</label>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    70% Complete (success)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
    50% Complete (info)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
    60% Complete (warning)
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    70% Complete (danger)
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="col-md-4">   
**//Label Goest Here Make fixes area for all labels and rest for progress bar**
    </div>



    <div class="progress">
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <label class="progress-label"style="font-size: large;"> Total memory:</label>
      </div>

<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:40%">
40% Complete (success)
    </div>
        </div>
```